# How to run a system generated android AOSP 12L system.img file on any android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, sony, sony-xperia

I am trying to run an android AOSP 12L system.img file-that was built for arm64- on an android emulator.
I had downloaded the android source code for the Sony Xperia 10 III device from the Sony developers guide. I followed the procedure that is mentioned on Sony's open device project website to do a custom build of the android AOSP 12L.
The build of the source code was successful after which the following .img  files were generated:

system.img,
boot-5.4.img,
ramdisk.img,
vbmeta.img,

I want to run these images on an emulator before flashing it to the Sony Xperia 10 III device.

I downloaded the Android Studio by Google. The emulator version installed on it is Android Emulator 31.2.10. Unfortunately, it does not have the provision to run a custom built image rather it only provides the android images provided by google.
I had downloaded the android 12 system.img for arm64 from the options listed and tried swapping that system.img file with the system.img file that was built by myself. But the emulator does not start and shows "Android emulator has been terminated".

I downloaded the Anbox emulator and that starts with its own android image and does not have the provision to run out system.img file.

Is there a way in which I can use any android emulator to run the system generated .img file?

Awaiting your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can create AVD images which can run on Android Emulator.

For the same, you can use

```
make -j32 sdk sdk_repo
```

command.

This will create an SDK for you which will be located

```
aosp-master/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk_phone_x86/sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip
```

You can use this zip for the creation of emulator and test your functionality. More on this can be found on this [website](https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd#sharing_avd_system_images_for_others_to_use_with_android_studio). 
Hope this helps !!

Comment: Few things to tweak here. First of all -j32 should change to number of cores in your build machine. Second, this command DID generated sdk_repo for me, but no sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng was generated.